Proof for Using Q-Function in Policy Gradient Formula
Currently I am reading the OpenAI spinning up document about policy gradient and actor-critic method. In this webpage,replace Return with Action value, I think they are trying to prove that the following two formulas are mathematically equivalent.,
I could not understand the derivation in that webpage. Is there any other resources for a clearer derivation for replacing the return $R(\tau)$ with the corresponding action value $Q^{\pi_{\theta}}(s_t,a_t)$? Thank you very much!
This article presents a different derivation.

the expectation of Q wrt the policy is V, and V is the expected return R

Read the Sutton and Barto derivation

I find another explanation which i think is very good.  link
